# MacBook Pro 17 2009 - fails to turn on after optical drive upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, optical-drive, logicboard, motherboard

The optical drive on my MBP stopped accepting discs, so I removed the optical drive and replaced it with the optical drive from my MBP 15 2009. Now it doesn't start.

During the upgrade I disconnected some cables, one of which I failed to reconnect, is this the issue?

[image: case off]
[image: close up]

How do I make my MBP 17 bootable once more?

Comment: Going through the Apple Technician Guide, looks like you pulled the plug on a critical cable incorrectly. Will report back once I'm done figuring it out.

Comment: I tried removing the optical drive and leaving that empty, but it still won't turn on...

Answer (score 1):

[Based on this iFixit guide (see step 13)](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+17-Inch+Unibody+Logic+Board+Replacement/3447), you seem to have disconnected the subwoofer/right speaker cable incorrectly, damaging the socket in the process (supported by [this diagram on page 185 of the Apple Technician Guide](http://tim.id.au/laptops/apple/macbook/mbp17_early09.pdf) of the logic board, labels working counterclockwise from the top right.)

[image: Use the flat end of a spudger to lift the subwoofer and right speaker connector out of its socket on the logic board. Pry up from beneath the wires.]

[image: LVDS, keyboard backlight, camera, optical drive, right speaker, IR/sleep, trackpad, keyboard, Express card cage, hard drive connector, battery indicator light (BIL)]

[Page 113 of the same guide](http://tim.id.au/laptops/apple/macbook/mbp17_early09.pdf) details how to properly remove the cable: it appears that you somehow damaged the socket whilst removing the cable.

[image: Use black stick under cable to remove. Keep connector level to board when disconnecting and reconnecting. Press evenly when reconnecting or connector can be tipped up and not fully seated.]

I'm not sure why this would cause your Mac to fail to boot however: perhaps it's an incompatible Superdrive, though my belief was that they are compatible. Can you detail how far you get into the boot process and look for any additional damage that may have occurred?

Comment: Also, there are supposed to be descriptions for the images, but I can't figure out how to get them to show up. :/

Comment: Thanks. A pair of external speakers are certainly cheaper than a new MBP! - Currently I press the power button and nothing happens (I can't hear anything + no lights appear). I've tried dis/connected to the charger.

Comment: @A T Odd, that's not good. I'd look for damage elsewhere on the computer.